# Website Color changes on different OS version

Tags: html, css, web, colors

I'm not really that new to website programming but have come across a weird bug I have not seen before.

The test concept site is [www.nomadcss.com.au/test](http://www.nomadcss.com.au/test)

The issue i'm having is the menu bar (green up the top) when you hover over it is meant to change to a nice blue gradient, it does this fine in all my tests.

I had a friend over and he looked on his laptop and the color is more of a purple than it is a blue???

We are both using laptops, both using Chrome (same version and both up to date), the only difference is screen res and my laptop being Win7 and his Win8.

Why would this happen? its a Hex value color so should it not be standard?

Comment: Try to set the color profile on your screen to `sRGB`, and I'm sure it looks purple to you as well.

Comment: my monitor is set to sRGB :(

Answer (score 0):

Colours can look different on different screens. That's nothing new.

But for what it's worth, `#5C5CE6` is indeed blue, but it's kind of a slightly pale blue which can very easily look purple on some displays. It looks purple on mine, for example!

Try lowering the amount of red and green in this colour, and it should start looking bluer.

Comment: That's the thing the main default color is #5C5CE6 which looks so blue :) I normally pick colors from a hex color picker, any way to adjust the RG values?

Answer (score 0):

I see it as a bit purple too..

It can be a different color profile applied, or different color settings on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You are delving into the realm of what color something is when its represented on some screen.

First off, you've got color adjustments in the various displays that change what a color is.  The menus that show up such as:

[image: monitor menu]

And with these tools, one can adjust the tint and colors of the screen.

Then you've got different calibrations for each monitor.  I've got two different types of monitors on my system.  When I look at the color profile for each, they are different.

[image]
[image]

You will see that there are other profiles that I can use on each other than the recommended one if I wanted to get a specific profile.

You and your friend may also wish to look at calibrating your display: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/calibrate-your-display and http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2414252,00.asp could be good resources for this.

Only after you have calibrated the displays can you say "that is what it looks like" and be reasonably sure that it will look the same on the other monitor.